# how to change class property inside a checkbox

Tags: javascript, validation, class, checkbox

if user inputs a value in the input field the class value on the checkbox will change automatically

input field:

```
 <input style="width:25px; margin-left:5px;" type="text" name="qtyA" id="qtyA"  />
```

checkbox:

```
<input id="INsrv1" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="1" />1<br>   
<input id="INsrv2" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="2" />2<br>   
<input id="INsrv3" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="3" />3<br>   
<input id="INsrv4" name="INopt" type="checkbox" value="4" />4<br>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#qtyA').on('change', function() {
    var max = $(this).val();
 });

    $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[max]] checkbox text')
    });
</script>
```

for ex:

the user inputs 3 in input field "qtyA"

value : 3

the maxCheckbox[] value on the script will change along with it

from maxCheckbox[1] to maxCheckbox[3]

the actual code:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#qtyA').on('change', function() {
    var max = $(this).val();
    alert(max);
 });

$("#srv").on('change', function() {
    var max = $('#qtyA').val();
    alert(max);
    var selVal = $(this).val();
        if (selVal == 'Inbound') { // Inbound
            $('.Inbound').show();
            $('.Outbound').hide();
            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')

            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[max]] checkbox text')
            $('#valOUT').val('');
            $('div#Outbound').find('span').prop('class','');

        }
        else if (selVal == 'Outbound') { // Outbound
            $('.Inbound').hide();
            $('.Outbound').show();
            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#INsrvOtr").prop('class','')

            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[max]] checkbox text')
                $('#valIN').val('');
            $('div#Inbound').find('span').prop('class','');

        }
        else {
            $('.Inbound').hide();
            $('.Outbound').hide();
            $('#valOUT').val('');
            $('#valIN').val('');
            $("[name$='INopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')
            $('div#Inbound').find('span').prop('class','');

            $("[name$='OUTopt']").prop('class','')
            $("#OUTsrvOtr").prop('class','')
            $('div#Outbound').find('span').prop('class','');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show before and after? Nothing in your actual code matches your question. Why do you have all that junk in the class? Perhaps you need to remove the quotes from around the validate statement

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").onchange(function() {
    $(this).attr('class','validate[minCheckbox[1],maxCheckbox[1]] checkbox text')
}
});
```

Comment: what i need is the integer of maxCheckbox to change when the user inputs an integer at qtyA